# How do I delete an extracted file in UNIX without deleting the compressed version?

Tags: linux, unix

I'm trying to delete "something.log.2014-02-24" without deleting "something.log.2014-02-24.gz"

After having tried...

> rm something.log.2014-02-24

... it deletes both of them.  What is the correct way to delete that file specifically without deleting the compressed version?

Comment: what flavor of *nix are you using? rm does allow for some glob style regex (e.g. * for wildcard) but without it..if you enter in exact name, it only deletes exact match.. i can't replicate your issue

Comment: Replace `rm` by `/bin/rm -iv`; perhaps `rm` is some strange alias at your place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't replicate your issue.

```
adaml@adaml-ws:~/test$ ls
test  test.txt
adaml@adaml-ws:~/test$ rm test
adaml@adaml-ws:~/test$ ls
test.txt
adaml@adaml-ws:~/test$
```

What distribution are you running? `rm` usually just deletes the specific filename you gave it.

Try running:

```
rm -i something.log.2014-02-24
```

That will ask you about each individual file before it gets removed. Use `y` or `n` to specify if you want to remove the file or not.

Comment: rm -i worked. Not sure why it was deleting the other if I didn't include a wildcard. Thanks!